# Jmeter : How to record, opening images in Light box in jmeter

Tags: lightbox, jmeter

In our site there is a portfolio page where thumbnail images are listed, when any one click on any image it will open in light box and on clicking the cross image the light box get close.

I have recorded this scenario through HTTP proxy , and found that under recording controller only upto portfolio page sampler is recorded but clicking on the thumbnail images events which i did is not recorded.

i then look into the view result tree listener and found that click on thumbnail images is listed there.
so what i want to know that how i can record opening images in light box in jmeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Light box opening is only client side (javascript) then what you're seeing is completely fine.

Jmeter is not a browser, it only records client to server traffic.

Comment: @pmd_ubik_ingenierie  when we are clicking on the thumbnail images it sending the image id to server and receiving the bigger image which we are re sizing on the fly and showing in the light box.

Comment: So at least JMeter will capture the request to server. Isn't it happening ? Which version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: Jmeter is not capturing that request , it is the problem , i am using apache-jmeter-2.9 version.

Comment: Do you see any errors in jmeter.log file in bin folder ? If it's a public site, can you mention it ?

Comment: @ PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE  the site is currently in our local domain ,which is not accessible from outside. i have checked the log file but not any error found.

Comment: Try setting log level to debug to see if any explanation. Does fiddler or firebug show these requests

Answer (score 0):

You should use "HTTP Request" sampler with direct url to images. If Jmeter doesn't record clicks anyway opening photos will load server so it's not reason to avoid them.